# Sum a sheet from a cell of a adding sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking how to sum in current sheet of a adding sheet, then show the total in a sheet "Mytotal"

My tab sheet look like this :

**...Sep-04-2015, Sep-05-2015 , Sep-06-2015, Productions, Mytotal..**

When i run my macro it copy the sheet"Production" and rename as a day in follow order and clear cell in  sheet"Productions".

What i am looking is how to sum a next adding Sheet as **Sep-07-2015, Productions,..** when i run my macro so what i need is: 
Sheet"Productions" A2 + A3 - Sheet"Sep-06-2015" A1, and the total show on sheet"Mytotal"

Answer (score 0):

Here, my approach for your program:

```
Public Sub copyAndExecute()

    Dim lastDateSheet As Date
    Dim productionIndex  As Integer
    Dim newSheetName As String

    'get sheet index of "Production" sheet
    productionIndex = Sheets("Productions").Index

    'get last sheet name which is date
    lastDateSheet = Sheets(productionIndex - 1).Name

    'Copy "Production" sheet before it
    Worksheets("Productions").Copy Before:=Worksheets("Productions")

    'Get new sheet name by adding one day
    newSheetName = Format(DateAdd("d", 1, CDate(lastDateSheet)), "MMM-dd-yyyy")

    'Rename new sheet
    Sheets(productionIndex).Name = newSheetName

    'Clear content
    Sheets(productionIndex).Cells.Clear

    'Execute cells
    Sheets("Mytotal").Range("A1") = Sheets("Productions").Range("A2") + Sheets("Productions").Range("A3") - Sheets(productionIndex - 2).Range("A1")

End Sub
```